# Preventing sql injection with MySql_*

Tags: php, mysql

lately it has been very irritating for me because I almost have a fully functioning site about to be launched. This may not seem like a problem, however my web host is running an old version of PHP so I cannot use MySqli_* or PDO, so I am stuck with the deprecated version (MySql_*). A user here on S.O has told me that it is IMPOSSIBLE to prevent sql injection attacks whilst running MySql_*.

Question: Is it impossible to secure my website from sql injection whilst using MySql_*?

Comment: It was right there, in the "Related" column, the whole time.

Answer (score 1):

it **is** possible to secure against sql injection attacks by well-escaping your variables, but the problem is ... JUST ONE TIME you do not escape a string .. you are vulnerable to sql injection, and that's the problem

if you are 100% sure that all inputs to database are well-escaped, then you are safe :)

Comment: You could easily mark question as Duplicate ! The related link has 100 times better answers !

Answer (score 1):

**Yes** it's possible.

Escape and quote correctly and you're done with that. **Escaping is not enough** you should also quote. mysqli_ advantage over mysql_ is that it escapes. PDO advantage over mysqli is that it auto quote. If you do them yourself then you're ready to launch your site.

Comment: You could easily mark question as Duplicate ! The related link has 100 times better answers !

Comment: @PratikCJoshi I can't mark it as duplicate according to my rep. however I think it's a more specific question, in that link they said use pdo use pdo while he can't use pdo.